# Azure Monitor integration with Kubernetes ingress controller

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-monitoring

I am looking for a solution to integrate traffic/access logs and metrics from Kubernetes Ingress into Azure Monitor. I am looking for something more than just raw logs and metrics. Something more similar to what Application Gateway shows.

I can select the ingress (Nginx, Traefik, Ambassador, Contour etc...) the only thing that I don't want to do is to use the Azure Application Gateway.

Does anyone know any solution that might provide it?

Comment: Hey, have you found your answer? I need to monitor my ingress controller

Comment: I've decided to use AppGateway in front, but picked V2 version and have one for all dev environments and another one for all prod environments.